# How to speed up my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query on a Database with 2700 records:

```
SELECT  
     inventura.Meno,
     inventura.DOD,
     inventura.IDproluc,
     inventura.IDbuxus,
     inventura.SM,
     inventura.cena,
     inventura.PocetBA,
     inventura.RezervacieBA,
     inventura.SkladBA,
     inventura.ShopBA,
     SUM(CASE WHEN objednavky.miesto = 'BA' OR objednavky.miesto = 'POST' THEN objednavky.ks ELSE 0 END) as cakajuciba,
     inventura.PocetBB,
     inventura.RezervacieBB,
     SUM(CASE WHEN objednavky.miesto = 'BB' THEN objednavky.ks ELSE 0 END) as cakajucibb 

     FROM inventura         

     LEFT JOIN objednavky
     ON (inventura.IDproluc=objednavky.hra) AND (objednavky.vybavene='0')         

     WHERE (true) // normally a condition goes here, this is when nothing is being searched for
     GROUP BY inventura.IDproluc
     ORDER BY inventura.meno ASC
```

The problem is it takes roughly 30-50 seconds to recieve the results, which is, I believe, far too long.

This query is used to search for a phrase in the collumn 'Meno', but if the search box is left empty, it displays whole table.

It needs to show the whole table, so displaying x rows is not an option.

**Could anybody please help me with some ideas how to speed it up?**

I have googled for some time but was unable to find something that would help me.

**More info:**

The database is Mysql 5.1,

PHP version 5.4

Function that pulls the data - `$result = mysql_query($sql)` (it's an older code, when I wrote it mysql functions were not deprecated yet)

The function pulls the data and then stores it to a multi-array to be later processed. (the processing itself takes nearly no time)

---

Edit:
result of EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type   table      type    possible_keys  key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE        inventura  ALL                                    2699    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE        objednavky ALL                                    2264
```

Comment: Use `explain your  query` in mysql and share the result to your question.

Comment: Might need to add indexes on the fields in your JOIN, the explain statement as @AbhikChakraborty stated would help to know this.

Comment: If you had rougly 3000 records and it takes more than 1 sec, I presume that you don't have any indexes.

Comment: `explain` will help identify the issues, but I suspect you need indexes on `inventura.IDproluc` and `objednavky.hra`

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN to the question. I have indexes on on inventura.Meno and inventura.IDproluc. Will try adding them to objednavky.hra and see if that helps.

Comment: nullability: thanks man, added index to `objednavky.hra` and it cut down from 50 seconds to 0,5 second. I set up indexes on that database about a year ago and never realised that field needs one as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing you could do is add table indexes to it. You can also use table aliases to simplify writing the query (look up the "AS" directive). As for indexes, it is based on the columns you join on and the columns you search on.

**Suggested columns that need indexing:** inventura.meno, inventura.IDproluc, objednavky.hra, and objednavky.vybavene

You will want to create a unique index for the primary key of any table (a unique ID for each row). You will want to look into indexes that span several columns which are helpful when doing searches/matching on multiple columns in a row at a time.

**References:**

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377652

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I already managed to fix it thanks to Nullability's comment on the original question - adding index to objednavky.hra reduced the time from 30-50 seconds to 0,3-0,5 seconds. I will definitely look into multi-collumn indices, thanks for the link. Although Nullability got me the right answer first, I cannot mark a comment as the right answer so I mark yours.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I at least built upon that knowledge with both my answer content and the links I provided.